# Terraform archive_file data block working locally but not in GitLab CI/CD pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, cicd

I'm using Terraform to create a Google Cloud Function and its associated Google Storage Bucket in a GitLab CI/CD pipeline.

I've defined a data "archive_file" "source" block to generate a zip archive of the function's source code and set the output_path to **.output/function.zip**.

```
   data "archive_file" "source" {
   type        = "zip"
   source_dir  = "./src"
   output_path = "./output/function.zip"
   }
```

This works fine when I run Terraform locally and the output folder is created in the working directory. However, when I run the same Terraform script in a GitLab CI/CD pipeline, I get an error that the **.output/function.zip** no such file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Is `./output/function.zip` defined as an `artifact` in the build stage of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file?

Bear in mind that files generated in a stage are only passed along to the next stage if they are defined as an artifact.

It's also being worth conscious of [the artifacts defined in the template](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml#L40-47) - ensure your modified artifacts section includes these properties (otherwise the `deploy` stage will fail from the missing plan file!)